# One-to-many relationship in the same table in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have groupTable(group_id,group_name,group_date,group_parent_id)
in face each group have many group child. 
I create groupModel and I want to begin coding is this right code to handle?

```
protected $_name = 'group';   
protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_group');  
protected $_referenceMap = array('Model_group' =>   
    array('columns' => array('group_parent_id') ,   
    'refTableClass' => 'Model_group' ,   
    'refColumns' => array('group_id') ,   
    'onDelete' => self::CASCADE ,   
    'onUpdate' => self::RESTRICT)  
);
```

Comment: I have also asked similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008519/problem-relating-a-zend-db-table-class-to-itself), but no answers

Answer (score -1):

One to many implies more than one table